# ScrollView Getting error undefined is not a function, js engine: hermes

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, scrollview

I Tried to using useRef to automate scroll if I press button
The idea is scroll with my scrollview and then I can press button to scroll to another set of view in my scrollview

this is my complete slider code

```
import { height } from 'deprecated-react-native-prop-types/DeprecatedImagePropType'
import { onChange } from 'deprecated-react-native-prop-types/DeprecatedTextInputPropTypes'
import React , {useState,useRef} from 'react'
import { StyleSheet, View , Text , ScrollView , Pressable , Image, Dimensions , TouchableOpacity} from 'react-native'


const WIDTH = Dimensions.get('window').width
const HEIGHT = Dimensions.get('window').height

const ImageSlider = ({slides}) => {
  const refScrollview = useRef()
  
  const [currentIndex,setCurrentIndex] = useState(0)
  // console.log(slides[currentIndex].banner)
  const [imageActive,setImageActive] = useState(1)

  const onChange = (nativeEvent) =>{
    if(nativeEvent){
      const slide = Math.ceil(nativeEvent.contentOffset.x / nativeEvent.layoutMeasurement.width)
      if(slide != imageActive){
        console.log(slide)
        setImageActive(slide)
        console.log(refScrollview.current)
      }
    }
  }

  

  return(
    <View style={{flex:1}}>
      <ScrollView
        ref={refScrollview}
        // onContentSizeChange={(contentWidth, contentHeight)=> {refScrollview.current.scrollToEnd({animated: true})}}
        onScroll={({nativeEvent}) => onChange(nativeEvent)}
        showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
        pagingEnabled
        horizontal
        style={styles.wrap}
      >
      {
        slides.map((e,index)=>
          // <Text>{e.banner}</Text>
          <View style={{flex:1}} key={index}>
          <Image source={e.banner}
          style={[styles.wrap]}
          >
          </Image>
          <Image  source={e.bannerFace}
          style={styles.bannerFace}
          >
          </Image>
          </View>

        )
      }
      </ScrollView>
      <View style={styles.wrapDot}>
      {
        slides.map((e,index)=>
          <TouchableOpacity key={index} style={imageActive == index ? styles.lineActive : styles.lineOnly} onPress={() => {
            refScrollview.current.scrollTo()}}>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        )
      }
      </View>
      
    </View>
  )
}

let styles = StyleSheet.create({
  backgroundImage: {
    flex:1,
    width: null,
    height: null,
    // width: 400,
    // height: 400,
    // resizeMode: 'cover',
  },
  bannerFace:{
    position:'absolute',
    bottom:0,
    right:0,
    flex: 1,
    width: 150,
    height: 150,
    resizeMode: 'contain'
  },
  wrap:{
    width:WIDTH,
    height:'100%'
  },
  wrapDot:{
    position:'absolute',
    bottom:20,
    left:50,
    flexDirection:'row',
    alignSelf:'center'
  },
  lineOnly:{
    padding:5,
    width:70,
    borderRadius:15,
    borderColor:'#CECECE',
    backgroundColor:'#CECECE',
    marginHorizontal:5
  },

  lineActive:{
    padding:5,
    width:70,
    borderRadius:15,
    borderColor:'#FFF',
    backgroundColor:'#FFF',
    marginHorizontal:5
  }
})

export default ImageSlider
```

I get the error TypeError: undefined is not a function, js engine: hermes
whenever i try to push/use this

```
onPress={() => {
        refScrollview.current.scrollTo()}}
```

It looks like there is no scrollTo() function , am I doing this wrong ? or is it my react node.modules ?

Comment: Please provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example.